# XSLT: I am trying to flatten XML element based on child element name using XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, transform, flatten

am trying to flatten an XML element based on a child element name using XSLT 1.0

The source XML:

```
<Contact>
  <ContactPurpose>
    <PurposeAsPlainText xmlns="cds_dt">Call</PurposeAsPlainText>
  </ContactPurpose>
  <ContactPurpose>
    <PurposeAsEnum xmlns="cds_dt">Call</PurposeAsEnum>
  </ContactPurpose>
</Contact>
```

Should be transformed into the following XML:

```
<Contact>
  <ContactPurpose>O</ContactPurpose>
  <ContactPurpose>Call</ContactPurpose>
</Contact>
```

The Logic is:

IF the child element name is “PurposeAsPlainText “ THEN
  set “O” for Other in destination

ELSEIF the child element name is “PurposeAsEnum” THEN
  copy the source value to destination

**EDIT 1**: I could be more clear as none of the solutions flattened the xml, please see revised source and dest XML.

**EDIT 2**: Here is the XML I was testing against.  The two tranform solutions below actually do work on my original xml but not the revised xml that I was testing using .NET 4.0 XslCompiledTransform.  Or should I make a new question?

```
<MyDS xmlns="cds" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <PatientRecord>
    <Demographics>
      <Contact>
        <ContactPurpose>
          <PurposeAsPlainText xmlns="cds_dt">Call</PurposeAsPlainText>
        </ContactPurpose>
        <ContactPurpose>
          <PurposeAsEnum xmlns="cds_dt">Call</PurposeAsEnum>
        </ContactPurpose>
      </Contact>
    </Demographics>
  </PatientRecord>
</MyDS>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you give example input and output for the case where the child element is "PurposeAsEnum".

Comment: Please see revised source and dest XML.  All the solutions output the same XML but forgot to flatten and remove the child element name.  The xml solution result in this comment is not the same as my desired ouput above.
 <ContactPurpose>
    <PurposeAsPlainText xmlns="cds_dt">Call</PurposeAsPlainText>
 </ContactPurpose>

Comment: @user610064: Thank you for the edit. You may have noticed that my answer uses exactly the XML document that you provide in the latest edit and produces exactly the wanted result.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev: For some reason when I run the XSL Transform it is not applying it and I get a normal copy.

Comment: Are you sure the solutions by me and Dimitre don't flatten/remove the PurposeAsPlainText element? I wonder if your input XML is not exactly what you posted -- maybe you have some other namespaces in there, or different namespace URIs?

Comment: @user610064: I always test my solutions. The current solution works with a dosen of different XSLT processors. The reason you are getting different result is one of the following: 1. You have modified the transformation. 2. You are applying the transformation on a different XML document. 3. You are using an incompliant/buggy XSLT processor.

Comment: The xml source doc actually uses a different namespace, I tried using the "cds" namespace in the xslt but I have the same issue.  Here is the source XML header tag:  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<OmdCds xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="cds">

Comment: Perhaps I should mention that the main XSD file "cds" references another XSD file "cds_dt".

Comment: Sorry everyone the original XSL files do work on the data first posted, but not on the actual xml file I was testing against.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This can be done in a simple and short way (no explicit conditionals)**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:x="cds_dt" exclude-result-prefixes="x">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="ContactPurpose/x:PurposeAsPlainText/text()">0</xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="ContactPurpose/*"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied to the following XML document** (extended to encorporate both cases of interest):

```
<Contact>
    <ContactPurpose>
        <PurposeAsPlainText xmlns="cds_dt">Call</PurposeAsPlainText>
    </ContactPurpose>
    <ContactPurpose>
        <PurposeAsEnum xmlns="cds_dt">Call</PurposeAsEnum>
    </ContactPurpose>
</Contact>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<Contact>
   <ContactPurpose>0</ContactPurpose>
   <ContactPurpose>Call</ContactPurpose>
</Contact>
```

**Explanation**:

Overriding the **[identity rule](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html)** and appropriate use of templates/match patterns.

**Update**: The OP has modified his XML document, which is now in a default namespace:

```
<MyDS xmlns="cds" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <PatientRecord>
        <Demographics>
            <Contact>
                <ContactPurpose>
                    <PurposeAsPlainText xmlns="cds_dt">Call</PurposeAsPlainText>
                </ContactPurpose>
                <ContactPurpose>
                    <PurposeAsEnum xmlns="cds_dt">Call</PurposeAsEnum>
                </ContactPurpose>
            </Contact>
        </Demographics>
    </PatientRecord>
</MyDS>
```

**Accordingly, here is a slightly modified transformation that produces the wanted result**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:x="cds_dt" xmlns:c="cds" exclude-result-prefixes="c x">
     <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
     <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

     <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
         <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
         </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="c:ContactPurpose/x:PurposeAsPlainText/text()">0</xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="c:ContactPurpose/*"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the new XML document (closest above), the new wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<MyDS xmlns="cds" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <PatientRecord>
      <Demographics>
         <Contact>
            <ContactPurpose>0</ContactPurpose>
            <ContactPurpose>Call</ContactPurpose>
         </Contact>
      </Demographics>
   </PatientRecord>
</MyDS>
```

Comment: Is it not applying the transform because I have two XSD files but only reference the 'sub' XSD in the XSLT? (see above comments). Or is C# XslCompiledTransform a buggy class / XSL parser?

Comment: @user610064: I always test my code before I post it. Apply the transformation with any compliant XSLT 1.0 processor (including .NET XslCompiledTransform) -- on the provided XML file, and you get the wanted result. Most probably you have a different XML document or have modifird the transformation, or both.

Comment: Please see edited question and the accompanying new commments re: namespaces. I copied your XSL exactly as you posted but not having success with it verbatim or with another namespace "cds".  strange...

Comment: @Dimitri Novatchev: Your solution does work on a free online tool (but not with .NET 4.0 XslCompiledTransform).  Your solution does not work with the same free online tool with my revised XML.  I used: http://xslt.online-toolz.com/tools/xslt-transformation.php

Comment: @Dimitri Novatchev: Correction your solution does work on the original XML snippet. thanks.

Comment: @user610064: Don't waste your time with "free online tools" and use true XSLT 1.0 processors. This solution produces the wanted results with all compliant XSLT processors -- I am working on a daily basis with more than 10 such XSLT processors and this transformation produces correct results with *all* of them. In case you want to do something else, with a different XML document -- the best way is to ask a *new* question.

Comment: @user610064: See the update of my answer (at the end of the answer).

Comment: Thank you very much and both of your solutions worked. I am starting to see a pattern, but wish I had a good overview resource for this with nice examples.  I will take your advice and not use that online tool then.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:cds="cds_dt" exclude-result-prefixes="cds">
<!-- identity transform - just copy things that don't have a better rule -->
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!- a rule for what needs changing -->
<xsl:template match="ContactPurpose[cds:PurposeAsPlainText] ">
    <ContactPurpose>O</ContactPurpose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This doesn't produce the wanted result.

Comment: When I first looked at this answer, I thought it was wrong, but then I concluded that the result it produced was consistent with the original, ambiguous question. I figured I'd leave it to the OP to decide whether it matched the output he actually wanted.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** modified the answer to fit the changed XML source document.

The description is not very clear, but here's what I think you're trying to do:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:cds_dt="cds_dt" xmlns:cds="cds"
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<!-- Identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cds:ContactPurpose">
   <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:choose>
         <!-- when there is a child element PurposeAsPlainText
            in the cds_dt namespace: -->
         <xsl:when test="cds_dt:PurposeAsPlainText">0</xsl:when>
         <!-- I'm guessing that PurposeAsEnum is also supposed to be
            in the cds_dt namespace. -->
         <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="cds_dt:PurposeAsEnum" />
         </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Your solution does work on a free online tool (but not with .NET 4.0 XslCompiledTransform). Your solution does not work with the same free online tool with my revised XML. I used: xslt.online-toolz.com/tools/xslt-transformation.php

Comment: Correction your solution does work on the original XML snippet. thanks.

Comment: @user610064: I suppose you are not to blame for not knowing that the snippet you originally posted was incompatible with the actual XML document you were using. The elements in your snippet are actually *different elements* than the ones in your actual document, because they belong to a different namespace. To avoid this confusion in the future, you need to either (a) understand XML namespaces, or (b) communicate all possibly relevant details when asking for help, to avoid leaving out critical details as happened this time.

Comment: @user610064: (b) is really impractical. I strongly recommend (a). Just as driving a manual-transmission car without learning about the clutch has high costs (for you and for the mechanic), so does working with XML namespaces without learning how they work.

Comment: I remember learning manual transmission years ago, I was great at accelerating, but stalled at every corner... :)